# JComboBox setSelectedItem does not work

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

I am trying to set the `setSelectedItem` of the `JComboBox` in the constructor of my `JPanel` class just after populating the combobox.

I am set the value for textbox, but I can't figure out why `setSelectedItem` does not seem to work. Any ideas?

```
public StudentProfilePanel(StudentInfo si) {

        yesButton.setBounds(50, 346, 69, 40);
        noButton.setBounds(121, 346, 56, 40);
        this.add(yesButton);
        this.add(noButton);
        setLayout(null);
        comboBoxYear.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(years()));
        comboBoxYear.setBounds(202, 365, 62, 23);
        if(si.birthdate!=null){
            //System.out.println("year value : ["+dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[2]+"]");
            comboBoxYear.setSelectedItem(dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[2]);

        }

        add(comboBoxYear);
        comboBoxMonth.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"}));
        comboBoxMonth.setBounds(285, 365, 56, 23);

        //set month value
        if(si.birthdate!=null){
            //comboBoxMonth.setSelectedItem(dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[1]);
            comboBoxMonth.setSelectedItem("04");
            System.out.println("month value : ["+dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[1]+"]");
        }
        add(comboBoxMonth);
        comboBoxDay.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(days()));
        comboBoxDay.setBounds(351, 365, 54, 23);
        if(si.birthdate!=null){
            //comboBoxDay.setSelectedItem(dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[0]);
            comboBoxDay.setSelectedItem(dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[0]);
        }
        add(comboBoxDay);

        textFieldFirstName = new JTextField();
        textFieldFirstName.setBounds(21, 321, 171, 21);
        add(textFieldFirstName);
        textFieldFirstName.setColumns(10);
        // set the value of first name
        textFieldFirstName.setText(si.firstName);

        textFieldLastName = new JTextField();
        textFieldLastName.setBounds(242, 321, 163, 21);
        add(textFieldLastName);
        textFieldLastName.setColumns(10);
        //set the value of the last name
        textFieldLastName.setText(si.lastName);

        JPanel panelPersonPhoto = new ImagePanel(
                "C:\\Users\\MDJef\\Pictures\\Wallpaper\\General\\11.jpg");
        panelPersonPhoto.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "",
                TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        panelPersonPhoto.setBounds(21, 20, 384, 291);
        add(panelPersonPhoto);
    }
```

Thanks very much.

helper methods that I used

```
    // jf : helper method
    public String[] years() {
        String[] results = new String[90];
        for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
            results[i] = Integer.toString(1900 + i);
        }
        return results;
    }

    // jf : helper method
    public String[] months() {
        String[] results = new String[12];
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            results[i] = Integer.toString(i + 1);
        }
        return results;
    }

    // jf : helper method
    public String[] days() {
        String[] results = new String[31];
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            results[i] = Integer.toString(i + 1);
        }
        return results;
    }

    // jf : helper method
    public String[] dateofbirth(String dob) {
        String[] tokens = dob.split("-");
        return tokens;
    }
```

Comment: Which of the ComboBoxes has the problem? Year, month or day?

Comment: years() returns a string array of years, all these combobox have problems, but let's look at the comboBoxMonth for now. With your solution, I now can set the value for comboboxmonth, but it failed again when I try to do it inside the if(si.birthdate!=null){ clause.

Comment: From what I can tell, there seems to be discrepancy between the combo box model values and what the `dateofbirth` method is returning...can you either add an example output (ie a `Date` value and the returned output of this method) or the method itself

Answer (score 2):

The values assigned to the combo box are not the same values you are trying set.

For example, the years are `String`s from 1900 - 1990, but if I supply a value `72`, there is no matching value in the combo box to match to.

Equally, your `days` and `months` methods are only returning values that are not padded (ie `01`), where as, in your code, you're trying to set the value using a padded value (ie `04`), meaning there is no matching value...

You have a number of options...

**You could...**

Convert all the values to an `int`, meaning that the values in the combo box are simply `int`s.  You would then need to convert the date values to `int`s as well.

This would make your helper code look more like...

```
public int[] years() {
    int[] results = new String[90];
    for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
        results[i] = 1900 + i;
    }
    return results;
}

public int[] months() {
    int[] results = new String[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        results[i] = i + 1;
    }
    return results;
}

public int[] days() {
    int[] results = new String[31];
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        results[i] = i + 1;
    }
    return results;
}

public int[] dateofbirth(String dob) {
    int[] tokens = dob.split("-");
    int[] values = new int[tokens.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < tokens.length; index++) {
      values[index] = Integer.parse(tokens[index]);
    }
    return index;
}
```

**A better solution**

Would be to use a `JSpinner`, which would take care of date rolling issues and validation automatically.

Check out [Using Standard Spinner Models and Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#standard)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `comboBoxMonth.setSelectedItem("04");` you try to select a newly created String which is not equal to the one which is in your `JComboBox`. Ergo it does not get selected.

You can try something like this instead:

```
String[] months = new String[] {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"};
comboBoxMonth.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(months));

comboBoxMonth.setSelectedItem(months[3]);
```

**Edit:** Try this. It uses the index of the item instead. Just make sure you add the months in order to the array.

```
String[] months = new String[] {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"};
comboBoxMonth.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(months));

if(si.birthdate!=null)
{
    comboBoxMonth.setSelectedIndex(Integer.parseInteger(dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[1]) - 1);
}
```

Comment: With your solution, I now can set the value for comboboxmonth, but it failed again when I try to do it inside the if(si.birthdate!=null){ clause

Comment: Do you get the output of `System.out.println("month value : ["+dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[1]+"]");` on your console when you run the program?

Comment: *"you try to select a newly created String which is not equal to the one which is in your JComboBox"* - My simple test didn't show this problem...

Comment: yeah, println works fine. month value : [04]
month value : [04]
month value : [07]
month value : [04]
month value : [04]
month value : [07]

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without knowing what `dateofbirth()` does. Does it create new Strings for it's return array?

Comment: it splits a string into string array by delima

Comment: It's maybe better to go with a selection via the index. See The update above.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I have just tried that, but it failed again. Thanks anyway. Something wired is going on with my code, this should not be that hard.

Comment: MadProgrammer was right when saying the problem was not with creating new objects, but with the correct content of the objects. JComboBox doesn't care about the addresses of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Not related to your problem, but:

```
yesButton.setBounds(50, 346, 69, 40);
noButton.setBounds(121, 346, 56, 40);
setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout and setBounds(...). Swing was designed to be used with Layout Manager. In the long run you will save time.

```
if(si.birthdate!=null){
```

Don't access variables in your class directly. Create a getter method to access the properties of your class.

```
//System.out.println("year value : ["+dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[2]+"]");
comboBoxYear.setSelectedItem(dateofbirth(si.birthdate)[2]);
```

Don't always try to force you code into a single statement. Instead do something like:

```
String birthdate = dateofbirth(si.birthdate[2]);
System.out.println("year value : [" + birthdate +"]");
comboBoxYear.setSelectedItem(birthdate);
```

This helps with your debugging because now you know that the variable you display is the same variable that you are trying to use in the setSelectedItem() method. It saves typing the statement twice and avoids typing mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:
`comboBoxMonth.setSelectedItem(index of the array);`

Answer (score 0):

For other developer with the same issue:
A closer look into the implementation of `setSelectedItem(Object anObject)` from `JComboBox` might help:

```
public void setSelectedItem(Object anObject) {
    Object oldSelection = selectedItemReminder;
    Object objectToSelect = anObject;
    if (oldSelection == null || !oldSelection.equals(anObject)) {

        if (anObject != null && !isEditable()) {
            // For non editable combo boxes, an invalid selection
            // will be rejected.
            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataModel.getSize(); i++) {
                E element = dataModel.getElementAt(i);
                if (anObject.equals(element)) {
                    found = true;
                    objectToSelect = element;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                return;
            }
        }

...
```

In the loop your object is compared with an object of the dataModel with the specific type `E`. In the implementation of equals() from String you can see a verification of class/interface, length and each character one after another. That means, our object must have same type and all characters must be the same!

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        if (this == anObject) {
            return true;
        }
        if (anObject instanceof String) {
            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
            int n = value.length;
            if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
                char v1[] = value;
                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
                int i = 0;
                while (n-- != 0) {
                    if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                        return false;
                    i++;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And this is the most annoying part `if (anObject.equals(element))` in  `setSelectedItem`! You cant override equals method from your element. For example `StudentInfo` and compare other types like strings or integers to it. Simple example. You implement combobox like this `JComboBox<StudentInfo>` and you want to select the student with `int id = 2;`. So it compares now `Integer` with `StudentInfo`. Here you have to override equals from `Integer`...

My proposal is to swap it. Create own class, add `boolean selectingItem` and override `setSelectedItem(Object anObject)` and `contentsChanged(ListDataEvent e)`(this method one-to-one). Nevertheless, I had side effects in one project...

Answer (score 0):

The item you wish to set as selected must **share the class** of the objects stored in the JComboBox.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] items = {"1", "2", "3"};
    JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox(items);
    jcb.setSelectedItem(3);
    System.out.println(jcb.getSelectedItem());
    jcb.setSelectedItem(3+"");
    System.out.println(jcb.getSelectedItem());
}
```

Output of the above code:

```
1
3
```